# How to rename tempfile used in mediarecorder?

Tags: java, android, rename, mediarecorder, temporary-files

I'm building an audio recorder using MediaRecorder and I want to rename the created file (because createTempFile adds a long random number to the file name)

So my main steps are:

```
    // I get the files on the directory I'm writing and the amount of files + 1
    File f = new File(myDirectory.toString());        
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    String fileNumber = String.valueOf(file.length+1);    

        try {
    // I create the temp file to record
      audiofile = File.createTempFile("record-"+fileNumber, ".3gp", myDirectory);

    } catch (IOException e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "sdcard access error");
      return;
    }    
    // START THE RECORDER
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
```

When the user clicks the stop button I add the file in the directoy

```
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, audiofile.getName());
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);


    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully added file in " +                     recordedDirectory+audiofile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The problem is that the files gets named e.g. "record-3824925563.3gp"

Is there anyway to rename the TempFile before saving it or preventing createTempFile() from adding the random number? Or any other solution to achieve this?

I tried creating a new file and then casting .renameTo(newFile) to my audio file but that didn't work.

EDIT:
As suggested by Michael I tried creating a New File with the parameters I want and renaming it

```
File AudioFile = new File(myDirectory+"/record-"+fileNumber+".3gp");

AudioFile.createNewFile();

audiofile.renameTo(AudioFile);
```

Which throws no errors. But the files endup with the same random numbers appended

**EDIT 2:**

As per jboi answer, which works great, I'm adding the final code I used. I created the file to make reference to it on my final MediaStore functions.

```
        File f = new File(myDirectory.toString());        
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    int fileNumber = file.length+1;

    audiofile = new File(String.format(Locale.US, "%s%crecord-%08d.3pg",
            quickrecorderDirectory, File.separatorChar, fileNumber));

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: 1) Instead of `createTempFile()` you can use the path and filename you finally want to (if you know it beforehand)  2) Call `renameTo(newFile)` on your `audiofile` and it will have the name given in `newFile` (if no error occurred). A `File` object isn't really a file, it is mainly the name and path information to denote a particular file or directory (existing or not)

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I couldn't make it work. Please see the edited question.

Comment: Forget the fileNumber that you create. It's unreliable and will produce errors in a multi threaded environment. What's the name you finally want to give to the file?

Comment: @Cruclax Read the docs, they state `renameTo()` returns false on failure, check for that. There is no need to create the file you want to rename to (this may even be the cause for the failure). Using multiple variable names which only differ in upper-/lowercase isn't a good idea. Using variable names starting with uppercase letter is against Java convention

Comment: @jboi I want to name the file "Record-[fileNumberOnThatFolder+1].3gp"

Comment: @MichaelButscher I will check that out and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply skip the step of creating a temporary file. If anything happens between start of recording and stop (user canceled, device turned off, app crashed, ...) then you can sort out file fragments and corrupted files in a housekeeping task later.

So, I would start recording straight forward into the final file. The file will have the filenumber+1 as a 8 digit number with leading zeros:

```
// I get the files on the directory I'm writing and the amount of files + 1
File f = new File(myDirectory.toString());        
File file[] = f.listFiles();
int fileNumber = file.length+1;

// START THE RECORDER
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile(
    String.format(Locale.US, "%s%crecord-%08d.3pg",
        myDirectory, File.separatorChar, fileNumber));
try {
    recorder.prepare();
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "error while preparing recording", e);
    // You might want to inform the user too, with a Toast
    return;
}
recorder.start();
```

Stopping and informing the media player is also straight forward:

```
recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
// Here comes all your code to inform Media scanner
```

In the end you need some housekeeping, that checks for incomplete files in the directory and deletes them. It could run on every startup `onCreate()`. To find out if a file is  complete, you might have a database already in use. In this database you can keep track of all known file names (`insert` when recording was stopped) and compare files with the database.

Comment: Yes. That worked fine! I'll edit my question to add the code I finally used. Thanks jboi.